# Is adding a user needs password

Tags: login, password, users, login-screen, adduser

In my Ubuntu after login by my user account, I want to create another user I intered bellow commands  :

```
adduser alex_2 -m
```

I created new user, but when I want to login, Ubuntu needs passwords and I did not gave that any password, as I mentioned I just typed `adduser alex_2 -m`. Am I should set a password? Also I can not login even when I set password blank .

Comment: 1. related http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-users-command/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can run the command:

```
sudo passwd username
```

to create a password for the user. ("username" needs to be changed to the given username)

You could also disable the password, when running the command `adduser`, by appending the option `--disabled-password`. But that isn't recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open system settings, and go to users. Click unlock, then on the user you want to change, then the Account Disabled, next to password, and choose one of the 3 options from drop down.